# Grounding new branch circuits in an existing subpanel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

Barn A contains the main panel.  Barn B has a subpanel fed from Barn A via (3) 2-0 aluminum conductors, 2 hot and 1 neutral, with a 60amp breaker in the main panel.  There is no grounding conductor between the main panel and subpanel.  The water line between barns is PVC.  Barn B was built in 2000.  There is no ground rod in Barn B.

My plans for Barn B include at least one new lighting branch circuit, and a 50 amp RV receptacle (NEMA 14-50r).

My question(s):

1. How should the ground wires for the existing and future 120V branches be connected?
2. How should the ground wire for the 50 amp RV receptacle be connected?

Comment: If Barn B was built in 2000 that was a blatant code violation at the time it was built. Unless - wouldn't happen to be metallic conduit the whole way? Or suspended above ground on a metallic cable? Still need a grounding electrode system at barn B, (unless there's a concrete slab with an Ufer ground in it.) Is the wiring in conduit of any sort (you might be able to add a [required] grounding conductor.)

Comment: Direct burial, unless the conduit ends underground.  I can see where the 3 wires come up out of the ground at Barn B.  Barn B is a wood-frame pole building, so no grounded rebar, piles, ect.

Comment: Well, that was poorly done, as even direct burial rated cable (if this is) is supposed to be protected where it comes out of the ground. I suspect you are going to have to add a grounding cable to sort this mess out. If the "electrician" involved is still around, you might want to sue them for malpractice. Depending on your actual loads, I guess you COULD consider the "transformer trick" where by using a transformer at each end of the cable, the supply at the far end becomes a new primary supply and you don't need a ground connection back to the source.

Comment: Some of the exposed wire can be blamed on erosion, but not all of it.  I was hoping to be able to safely avoid running a wire; it's just over 400 feet between barns.  Actual load probably wont exceed 30 amps.  A 16 amp AC unit (actual running current, 20 amp circuit), a 1.5 amp camper fridge, a handful of CFL lights, and a 750 watt microwave.

Comment: @Greenfun2 -- are you OK with parts that you are going to have to do a bit of work to find? There is a way out of this without running wire per se, but it requires something (namely, a distribution transformer) that's rather outside what big-box stores carry....

Comment: One more thing: is there a space outside Barn B that can be used for a fairly sizeable piece of electrical equipment?

Comment: Oh, how much load is there *in addition* to the RV receptacle?